# Resteasy MessageBodyReader error message

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

So, I have a REST application and looks like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/getpartners")
public HashMap<Integer, PartnerEntityDTO> getPartners() throws NamingException {
     //body
}
```

I implemented my REST client using ResteasyClient framework and looks like quoted below according to the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html)

```
@GET
@Path("/getpartners")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
HashMap<Integer, PartnerEntityDTO> getPartners();
```

The point is that, I would like to get an HashMap on client side from REST service and I get it without any issue if I'm usin a browser. But If I'm using swing client than something is wrong. I use this code in my swing client to handle the call and response.

```
    //Resteasy client
    RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
    PartnerServiceClientInterface partnerServiceClientInterface = ProxyFactory.create(PartnerServiceClientInterface.class, "http://localhost:8080/dilib/partners");
    **//Sources.java:66**
    String restResponse = partnerServiceClientInterface.getPartners().toString();
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray partnerDataInJson = jsonParser.parse(restResponse).getAsJsonArray();
    int size = partnerDataInJson.size();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    HashMap<Integer, PartnerEntityDTO> partnerDataFromServer = new HashMap<Integer, PartnerEntityDTO>();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        PartnerEntityDTO deserializedPartnerEntityDTO = gson.fromJson(partnerDataInJson.get(i), PartnerEntityDTO.class);
        partnerDataFromServer.put(i, deserializedPartnerEntityDTO);
    }
```

The error message is this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Integer, com.sayusiando.java.dilib.dilibcore.server.entities.core.dto.PartnerEntityDTO>
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:522)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:513)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.readFrom(BaseClientResponse.java:414)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:376)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:349)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:54)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:120)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:88)
at $Proxy16.getPartners(Unknown Source)
at com.sayusiando.java.dilib.client.swing.modules.core.fields.sources.Sources.processPartnerDataFromRESTServer(Sources.java:66)
at com.sayusiando.java.dilib.client.swing.modules.core.fields.sources.Sources.initComponents(Sources.java:45)
at com.sayusiando.java.dilib.client.swing.modules.core.fields.sources.Sources.<init>(Sources.java:26)
at com.sayusiando.java.dilib.client.swing.modules.core.DilibCoreSwingClient.valueChanged(DilibCoreSwingClient.java:155)
at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(JTree.java:2820)
at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(JTree.java:3191)
at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:629)
at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:1078)
at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:287)
at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:170)
at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPath(JTree.java:1598)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.selectPathForEvent(BasicTreeUI.java:2311)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(BasicTreeUI.java:3520)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTreeUI.java:3459)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6285)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4235)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I googled for this error message and the documentation of the Resteasy is linket at the Interceptors part, but it is not clear for me what is the problem.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Is the jettison provider in your classpath? If you are using maven, add this dependency:</strike>

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Replace `${resteasy.version}` with the version you are using.

*EDIT :*

From the [RestEASY documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#JAXB_Map):

> Your parameter or method return type must be a generic with a String as the key and the JAXB object's type.

Working testcase:

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ProxyFactory;
import org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockDispatcherFactory;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.tjws.TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

public class JsonMapTest {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class PartnerEntityDTO {
        @XmlElement String name;

        public PartnerEntityDTO(){}
        public PartnerEntityDTO(String name){ this.name = name;  }
    }

    @Path("/")
    public interface Service {
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Path("/getpartners")
        public Map<String, PartnerEntityDTO> getPartners() throws NamingException;
    }

    public static class ServiceImpl implements Service{

        public Map<String, PartnerEntityDTO> getPartners() throws NamingException {
            Map<String, PartnerEntityDTO> map = new HashMap<String, PartnerEntityDTO>();

            map.put("1", new PartnerEntityDTO("one"));

            return map;
        }
    }

    static final TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer server = new TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void start(){
        server.setPort(8080);
        server.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void stop(){
        server.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        server.getDeployment().getRegistry().addSingletonResource(new ServiceImpl());
        String url = "http://localhost:8080";
        Service service = ProxyFactory.create(Service.class, url);
        Map<String, PartnerEntityDTO> partners = service.getPartners();

        assertEquals(1, partners.size());
        assertEquals("1", partners.keySet().iterator().next());
        assertEquals("one", partners.values().iterator().next().name);

    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(new ServiceImpl());

        MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/getpartners");
        MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

        dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

        assertEquals("{\"1\":{\"partnerEntityDTO\":{\"name\":\"one\"}}}", response.getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I put it on the classpath, but the error is the same. I think I missed something. Now, I'm reading the jersey and resteasy docs and try to workaround this issue - I mean how can I get HashMap<Integer, Entity> type on client side.

Comment: Adding the dependency org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jettison-provider worked for me